# Compiling the Python Interface for Caffe using CMake

Tags: python, cmake, makefile, caffe

On Ubuntu, I have downloaded Caffe to `~/caffe`, and compiled it using cmake with the CMakeLists.txt file that it comes with. I now want to start using the python interface. According to the examples, I need to add `~/caffe/python` to the `PYTHONPATH` variable in my `.bashrc` file. Then, I need to use use `import caffe` in a python script. However, this gives me the error: `ImportError: No module named 'caffe'`.

If I use the line `import caffe` in my python script, this means that there must exist a file called `caffe.py` in the directories defined by `PYTHONPATH`. Is that correct? However, I cannot find any files called `caffe.py` on my system. But the `CMakeLists.txt` file is supposed to build the python files, and has the line `add_subdirectory(python)`.

Does anybody have any experience with this? Had anybody got the python interface working by compiling with cmake?

Thanks.

Comment: `I have downloaded Caffe to ~/caffe, and compiled it using cmake` - Have you *installed* caffe after building?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have `caffe.py` in `~/caffe/python`. In this case you should have a subfolder `~/caffe/python/caffe` that should have `__init__.py` file in this subfolder. Make sure you have `~caffe/python/caffe/_caffe.so` file - this shared object should be created during compilation.
It may be the case that you added the right folder to your `.bashrc`, but have you loaded/sourced the file after updating it?